Execution failed for task ':generateDebugBuildConfig'. Failed to calculate the value of task ':generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'namespace'
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':generateDebugBuildConfig'.
> Error while evaluating property 'namespace' of task ':generateDebugBuildConfig'
   > Failed to calculate the value of task ':generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'namespace'.
      > Failed to calculate the value of property 'namespace'.
         > Manifest file does not exist: E:\My Projects\MobileApp\herb_identifier\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Encoutering this exception when trying to build my flutter app
Done several configurations but not working
I'll be very thankfull if you could help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


Manifest file does not exist: E:\My Projects\MobileApp\herb_identifier\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

The error is obviously complaining about the missing AndroidManifest.xml
file; check this path :
E:\My Projects\MobileApp\herb_identifier\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

and make sure that AndroidManifest.xml exists in your project.
If it does not create one.
If it does exist it is most likely about namespace not being initialized in the build.gradle file, so go to this path android/app/build.gradle and add this line like this:
android {
namespace = "com.example.your_project_name" //  replace it with your project's name
compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion
.
.
.

